# Clamp the output of constant current source and capacitor to particular voltage

Tags: capacitor, constant-current

How do I need to saturate the output to 891mV?
The current source is 1uA and the capacitor value is 3.76n
I need the output to ramp up till 3.35ms then saturate to 0.891V
[image: Schematic]

Comment: is this a real circuit you need to build, or are you trying to create a specific stimulus for use in a simulator? If the former, what are your tolerances? And just being curious, why?

Comment: I'm simulating the circuit

Comment: Use  PWL then, draw what waveform you like

Comment: Smells of an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a voltage detect circuit possibly a comparator to detect when you reach the desired voltage and then a switch to turn of the current source possibly a pmos transistor when you attain that voltage.

Comment: The mos acts as a switch, so when we attain that voltage we will disconnect the current source. Am I right?

Comment: That is it. ....